# Mapbox and SMCalloutView

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, smcalloutview

I am using Mapbox for a project and it's a requirement to be able to customize the `CalloutView`. However I do not seem to have access to the callout view. I attempted to add it to the podfile and update the `pod`; however, I get multiple warnings pertaining to the fact that their is now two versions in the project, one already in mapbox and the new one I added o the project. If I remove the `SMCalloutView` podfile and delete the cache and clean the project it stops working again.

Any Assistance would be well appreciated.

```
objc[17031]: Class SMCalloutView is implemented in both /~~USER__PATH~~/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsOpen-fvkxaevysthypdcmxdjcmgzfidty/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMCalloutView.framework/SMCalloutView and /~~USER__PATH~~/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsOpen-fvkxaevysthypdcmxdjcmgzfidty/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[17031]: Class SMCalloutMaskedBackgroundView is implemented in both /~~USER__PATH~~/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsOpen-fvkxaevysthypdcmxdjcmgzfidty/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMCalloutView.framework/SMCalloutView and /~~USER__PATH~~/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsOpen-fvkxaevysthypdcmxdjcmgzfidty/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[17031]: Class SMCalloutBackgroundView is implemented in both /~~USER__PATH~~/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsOpen-fvkxaevysthypdcmxdjcmgzfidty/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SMCalloutView.framework/SMCalloutView and /~~USER__PATH~~/Xcode/DerivedData/WhatsOpen-fvkxaevysthypdcmxdjcmgzfidty/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```